# Robust input for lottery tickets

Tags: java, array

I've made a method that provides a robust way for a user to fill out a lottery ticket. During this process I found out that Java also provides syntax for labels. That was very astounding for me. But I also was told that using goto-like code can be a bad smell. But I've not found a way to make my code "more beautiful".

What do you think? Is it tolerable to use a label to solve this problem? Are there other aspects that have to be improved?

#### The following things are checked:

- Is the entered number really a valid number?
- Is the number in a valid range?
- Was this number already entered?

### Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    private static final int DRAW_SIZE = 6;
    private static final int LOWER_RANGE = 1;
    private static final int UPPER_RANGE =  49;
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numbers[] = saveIntArrayFromUserInput();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

    // lets the user create an int array
    // assures that all values are unique numbers between lower and upper range
    private static int[] saveIntArrayFromUserInput() {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        
        main_loop:
        while (numbers.size() < DRAW_SIZE) {
            int number = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            // check if input is a number
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a valid number.");
                continue;
            }

            // check if input is in range
            if (number > UPPER_RANGE || number < LOWER_RANGE) {
                System.out.println("Your number isn't between " + LOWER_RANGE + " and "
                                  + UPPER_RANGE);
                continue;
            }

            // check if input is unique
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if (numbers.get(i) == number) {
                    System.out.println("You've entered this number already.");
                    continue main_loop;
                }
            }
            
            numbers.add(number);
        }

        int[] numbersArray = new int[numbers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) numbersArray[i] = numbers.get(i);
        Arrays.sort(numbersArray);
        return numbersArray; 
    }
}
```

### Example Output

```
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 6
You've entered this number already.
Enter a number: 600
Your number isn't between 1 and 49
Enter a number: bla
Enter a valid number.
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 3
You've entered this number already.
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Using exceptions to determine whether a variable is of a certain type will cause a slow program

Comment: What is a good alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most lotteries, order doesn't matter, so consider using a Set instead of an array of numbers.

That means that your check for already present becomes a simple method call, so no need to break out of two levels of loops.

Java's `continue LABEL` and `break LABEL` aren't as dangerous as C's `goto`, (they are constrained to work with structured programming, and object cleanup is performed when leaving scope, as normal) but I still recommend that they should be used sparingly, due to the cognitive load imposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is true that the order doesnt matter, but I like ordering the numbers because it looks better.

Comment: IMO there is no reason to use labels and it this feature should never be used

Comment: If you want order, you can still use a Set. TreeSet is ordered...

Comment: Thanks for the TreeSet-Advice! I will look it up in java docs

Answer (score 1):

This won't handle the Powerball lottery correctly.  With Powerball, the Powerball number may duplicate one of the other numbers.  It's drawn separately from a different pool.

Since you don't sort until you create a new array to hold the numbers, you could put the initial numbers in a `Set`.  Then you don't need your labeled `continue`, nor that entire nested loop.

You can more easily convert a collection to an array with

```
int[] numbersArray = numbers.toArray(new int[numbers.size()]);
```

No explicit loop needed.  Note that this works whether `numbers` is a `List` or a `Set`, since both are `Collection`.